# Create multiple providers for same SQS class using Google Guice

Tags: java, binding, amazon-sqs, guice, guice-3

I have two SQS queues from which I want to listen to messages using two different message handlers. I am using Guice to bind and initialise the different consumers and message handlers. However, I am unable to bind the respective consumer to corresponding handler.

*Consumer - TransactionQueue, Handler - TransactionMessageHandler*

*Consumer - RetryQueue, Handler- RetryMessageHandler*

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for com.amazon.aft.sqsmessageconsumer.messaging.sqs.SqsMessageHandler was bound.
  Did you mean?
    * com.amazon.aft.sqsmessageconsumer.messaging.sqs.SqsMessageHandler annotated with 
@com.google.inject.name.Named(value="TransactionMessageHandler")
    * com.amazon.aft.sqsmessageconsumer.messaging.sqs.SqsMessageHandler annotated with 
@com.google.inject.name.Named(value="RetryMessageHandler")
 while locating com.amazon.aft.sqsmessageconsumer.messaging.sqs.SqsMessageHandler
for the 1st parameter of com.config.providers.ListenerProvider.<init>(TransactionConsumerProvider.java:23)
  at com.config.ListenerModule.configure(ListenerModule.java:26) (via modules: com.service.ServiceModule -> com.config.ListenerModule)
```

I have used `@Named` annotation to differentiate the consumers and handlers. Here is how my bindings look like:

```
@Override
  protected void configure() {

        bind(SqsConsumer.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("TransactionQueue"))
            .toProvider(TransactionConsumerProvider.class)
            .asEagerSingleton();        

bind(SqsMessageHandler.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("TransactionMessageHandler"))
            .toProvider(TransactionMessageHandlerProvider.class)
            .asEagerSingleton();

        bind(SqsConsumer.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("RetryQueue"))
            .toProvider(RetryConsumerProvider.class)
            .asEagerSingleton();

        bind(SqsMessageHandler.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("RetryMessageHandler"))
            .toProvider(RetryMessageHandlerProvider.class)
            .asEagerSingleton();
    }
```

Here are the classes for the consumers and the handlers:

**TransactionConsumerProvider.class**

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public final class TransactionConsumerProvider implements Provider<SqsConsumer> {

    @Named("TransactionMessageHandler")
    private final SqsMessageHandler sqsMessageHandler;

    @Override
    public SqsConsumer get() {
        // initializing transaction SQS queue
        final SqsConsumer consumer = new SqsConsumer(
            "TransactionQueue",
            sqsClientBuilder,
            sqsMessageHandler,
            new SimpleMessageProcessingFailureHandler()
        );
    }
```

**TransactionMessageHandlerProvider.class**

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public final class TransactionMessageHandlerProvider implements Provider<SqsMessageHandler> {

    @Override
    public SqsMessageHandler get() {
       // Initialising TransactionMessageHandler 
    }
```

**RetryConsumerProvider.class**

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public final class RetryConsumerProvider implements Provider<SqsConsumer> {

    @Named("RetryMessageHandler")
    private final SqsMessageHandler sqsMessageHandler;


    @Override
    public SqsConsumer get() {
       // initializing retry SQS queue
    }
```

**RetryMessageHandlerProvider.class**

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public final class RetryMessageHandlerProvider implements Provider<SqsMessageHandler> {

    @Override
    public SqsMessageHandler get() {
       // Initialising RetryMessageHandlerProvider 
    }
```

I think I have used `com.google.inject.name.Names` import correctly, but I am willing to try any new suggestions to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: can you share a reproducer ?

Comment: Check the order in which you're binding dependencies when using eager.